# Browsers not recognizing styling for my paragraph tags

Tags: css, html

For whatever reason cannot get my browser or editor to recognize the styling that I have set for my paragraph tags. Here is my code. Any help is much appreciated :)

```css
/* COLORS */
$color1: #000000;
$color2: #111111;
$color3: #222222;
$color4: #333333;
$color5: #444444;
$color6: #555555;

/* BODY TEXT */
p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* H1-H6 */
h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styleguide_sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<title>Title of project goes here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
 <strong>This is body text:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id malesuada felis. Sed efficitur scelerisque tortor, a ultricies tortor vestibulum non. Proin id nisi condimentum, ultrices tellus id, vehicula massa. Ut laoreet, purus at malesuada ornare, orci dui mattis elit, fermentum mollis dolor quam ut orci. Morbi consequat non nibh eget aliquam. Donec diam velit, volutpat ut ornare in, ultricies ac est. Aenean a ligula auctor, congue elit nec, fringilla eros. Mauris placerat ligula id neque fringilla, ut congue quam pellentesque. Aenean lacinia, velit ut fringilla tincidunt, tortor nisi faucibus quam, sed lobortis justo ex ac ipsum. Etiam et dolor eget metus ultrices tincidunt non ac erat. Integer non accumsan mi, sed consequat purus.  
 </p>
 <h1>
 This is Header 1
 </h1>
 <h2>
 This is Header 2
 </h2>
 <h3>
 This is Header 3
 </h3>
 <h4>
 This is Header 4
 </h4>
 <h5>
 This is Header 5
 </h5>
 <h6>
 This is Header 6
 </h6>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested this is firefox & chrome, the only place it seems to be working is Dreamweaver. Im sure there is a simple solution. I just can't seem to identify what it is.

ps: The H1 - H6 tags seem to be working fine. The only thing that won't work is the styling for the P tag.

Comment: Looks like color declarations messing with the css...

Comment: That was it! thank you. Good eye I could not figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can close the question and to help others.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably since your font does not support the given weight. If you you use the following you can get bold text. Normal weight is usually 400 and bold weight is usually 700. Support for other weights is not guaranteed as far as I know.

```
p { 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The color code in your `p` rule (#ffffff) stands for white, so you won't see that text since it's white letters on a white background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your color decoration at the beginning of your css:

```
/* COLORS */
$color1: #000000;
$color2: #111111;
$color3: #222222;
$color4: #333333;
$color5: #444444;
$color6: #555555;
```

is messing with the rest of the stylesheet.

If you want to use variables in your css take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). These preprocessors extend the normal css with handy features as variables and nesting.